# Fetching a large block of data using NHibernate

Tags: database, nhibernate

#### I have some 3 million rows of data to show on data grid using C#.

Currently using NHibernate to fetch data from database sqlserver 2005.
***NHibernate*** takes lots of time to get data. Is there any way to retrieve data from data from database efficiently using **NHibernate**.

**---Edit----**
As the application has huge data to operate upon, loading all rows is just a worst case scenario.
 In a normal use user will load 10k rows. No of displaying rows can be minimised by using paging but as some rows are dependent on others I need to load all data while initializing the app.

**NHibernate gets slow even with 1000 rows.** Any suggestions to improve the performance.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you simply selecting all of the data or are you performing updates on it and persisting it back to the DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Stateless Session](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-statelesssession) to get the data.

http://ayende.com/blog/4137/nhibernate-perf-tricks
http://darioquintana.com.ar/blogging/2007/10/08/statelesssession-nhibernate-without-first-level-cache/

But first ask your self do you really need to display millions of rows. What value does that give to your user? Can they easily locate the data they want?

Also, `DataGrid` itself will take a large amount of memory (regardless whether you are using Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.NET...). Memory to store the data itself, plus the memory to store additional DataGrid column / cell metadata.

Consider having only a subset of data instead. You could either allow the user to filter thru the data and/or add paging. Filter and paging can be translated to HQL / Criteria / Linq / QueryOver queries and eventually to SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks for the response....I am using collections to store data so cannot use stateless session.

Comment: @Dewashish Try to disable lazy loading for your child collections. Maybe you have Select N+1 problem. Or, try to fetch them when doing queries: http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2011/09/18/nhibernate-pitfalls-select-n-1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation here is not to use an ORM to fetch this size of data but then my second point is why would you want to fetch 3 Million rows of data and show it in a grid?

No user can possibly want to scroll through 3 Million lines of a table.

You could use a paged data system to request only the page you are viewing at any one time. Or you could filter the data for a smaller subset that the user is interested in.

If you have 3 Million records maybe the data needed is an analysis of those records.

I would take a look at some of these resources:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164022.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/08/asp-net-mvc-paging-sorting-filtering-using-the-mvccontrib-grid-and-pager.aspx

Comment: I need NHibernate because any of these rows might be updated by the application and using an ORM will ease the problems associated with mapping.

Answer (score 0):

As the application grows in complexity and the data on which they thrive upon becomes complex, the generality of such OR mapping engines may lead to various performance and scalability bottleneck. Applications cannot scale linearly with the increasing transactional requirements. Caching is one technique which can enhance the performance of the NHibernate app. Infect NHibernate provides a basic, not-so-sophisticated in-process L1 cache out of box. However, it doesn’t provide features that a caching solution must have to have a notable impact on the application performance. So its better to use a 2nd level cache, it may help you to increase the performance of your Nhibernate App. There are many third party NHibernate 2nd Level cache are provider are available there but I'll recommend you to use **NCache**. Here is a good read about it,

http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/nhibernate-l2cache-index.html